# It is possible to Generate array of strings in pact.io

Tags: pact

It is possible to create Array of strings in pact.io for example i want to create contract for below json format.

values:[values1,values2,values3]

but i have looked at pact.io documentation didn't find anything related

Comment: Yes this is absolutely supported. Our docs don't have an example for every single possible sample API. What language are you using, what have you tried so far, and what docs have you read?

Comment: Mathew i am using java and version i am using 'pact-jvm-provide ' 3.6.4 . https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/200 this issue provides some info.I have tried using object("value").stringType("values"). but this stringType is creating key value pair instead of strings .and I also tried using array() and eachKeyMappedToAnArrayLike() but none of them provide above structure.